# Change styling of p:selectOneMenu

Tags: css, primefaces, styling, bootsfaces

I have implemented the above selectOneMenu in Bootsfaces and the below selectOneMenu in primefaces.

I need the implementation in primefaces but styling as in bootsfaces.

**How can I change the styling of the second selectonemenu as the above selectOneMenu?**

I need to remove the grey borders.
Can anyone please suggest me.

**EDIT -**

[image]

After adding the suggested css.. primefaces selectonemenu is displayed as above on selecting the selectonemenu.

**I need to align the highlighted box around the down arrow symbol in the selectonemenu and change the highlighted box color to grey.**

Please suggest further modifications. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Just set `background-color: #fff !important;` to `ui-selectonemenu` class, if you want to change style of all the select elements. Or add specific class to your `p:selectOneMenu` and define that CSS.

Comment: Why not just use the bootsfaces one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have following display of the `p:selectOneMenu` with the custom CSS classes (`form-control & radius-none`) on my specific screen:

[image]

**XHTML:**

```
<p:selectOneMenu styleClass="form-control radius-none" ...
...
...
```

**CSS:**

```
.ui-selectonemenu.form-control {
    color: #555 !important;
    display: block !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding: 5px 10px !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
    border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
}

.radius-none {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.ui-selectonemenu.form-control .ui-selectonemenu-trigger {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 16px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 !important;
    border: none !important;
    margin-top: 5px !important;
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

**Update:** The other CSS related to `.ui-selectonemenu-label` and `.ui-inputfield` is also part of the rendered HTML, which is generic in my case:

```
.ui-selectonemenu .ui-selectonemenu-label {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: normal;    
}

.ui-selectonemenu .ui-selectonemenu-label.ui-inputfield.ui-corner-all {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.ui-inputfield {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #ffffff;
    font-weight: normal;
    outline: medium none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 #8f8f8f!important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 #8f8f8f!important;
}
```

**NOTE:** If you want to change the style of all `p:selectOneMenu` elements in general, then remove the custom classes.

Comment: Thankyou so much..@Parkash Kumar. But need some modification. I have added the image after adding suggested css. Please suggest further modifications.Thankyou.

Comment: Thankyou for the detailed explanation... Can you please tell me what more to add in xhtml <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="form-control radius-none" ... ?

Comment: No need to add anything in <p:selectOneMenu styleClass> except form-control and radius-none?

Comment: Yes, just add these two classes.

Comment: Thankyou so much @Parkash Kumar

Comment: Welcome, happy coding!

Comment: Basically, your approach is to redefine the broken CSS of the PrimeFaces widget. Awesome! The only disadvantage of this approach is that you have to do it for every PrimeFaces component you want to use. I've described a more general solution in my [article on BeyondJava.net](https://www.beyondjava.net/blog/how-to-use-bootsfaces-and-primefaces-in-the-same-project/).

Comment: Actually, we are using just PrimeFaces in our Liferay environment. That is why we redefine the core CSS of the components in our theme to reflect it to portlet's. So, I did not require to consider the BootFaces components.

Comment: I have edited the question after adding the suggested css.Please suggest further modifications @ParkashKumar.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago, I've written an article about the problem. It includes a link to a demo project solving many (hopefully most) incompatibilities to PrimeFaces: https://www.beyondjava.net/blog/how-to-use-bootsfaces-and-primefaces-in-the-same-project/